# Wait time differences in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I'm trying to track the different wait time classes for current Oracle sessions but I must be misunderstanding something.  When I compare the `sum(time_waited)/1000` for a given session in `gv$session_wait_class` its often greater than the value of `seconds_in_wait` from `gv$session` and sometimes even greater than its `last_call_et` which I thought would be the total time...

What am I missing here?  Why aren't they the same?  I'm comparing numbers with this query:

```
select last_call_et,wait_time,seconds_in_wait,wait_time_micro/1000000,
(SELECT SUM(time_waited)
  FROM gv$session_wait_class ot WHERE
  ot.sid = ses.sid
  AND ot.serial#                          = ses.serial#
  AND ot.inst_id                          = ses.inst_id
  )/1000 as wait_time_class from gv$session ses where sql_id is not null;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the description of [`v$session`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10820/dynviews_3016.htm):

> `SECONDS_IN_WAIT`
>   If the session is currently waiting, then the value is the amount of time waited **for the current wait**. If the session is not in a wait, then the value is the amount of time **since the start of the last wait**.
>   This column has been deprecated in favor of the columns WAIT_TIME_MICRO and TIME_SINCE_LAST_WAIT_MICRO.
>
> `WAIT_TIME_MICRO`
>   Amount of time waited (in microseconds). If the session is currently waiting, then the value is the time spent **in the current wait**. If the session is currently not in a wait, then the value is the amount of time waited in **the last wait**.

These aren't cumulative measures, they're only related to the current or last wait event.

[`v$session_wait_class`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/dynviews_3025.htm) on the other hand sums up the times a session has been in different wait classes.

> `V$SESSION_WAIT_CLASS` displays the time spent in various wait event operations on a per-session basis.
>
> `TIME_WAITED`
>   Amount of time spent in the wait class by the session

So it's understandable that the times indicated in `[g]v$session_wait_class` are larger than the ones you're looking at in `[g]v$session`.
The opposite could be true too though, depending on when a wait is accounted in the wait class view. If it's accounted once the wait event is over and not dynamically (I *think* that's what happens), the current wait could be larger than the sum of previous waits.